# Are there benefits to buying the box version versus the Steam version of Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5, steam, version-differences

Is there any benefit to buying the box version of Civlization 5 on Steam versus the box, or vice versa?

Comment: You don't have to go to a shop or have to wait until it shipped :)

Comment: Not having to go to Gamestop is always a benefit for me.

Comment: I'd go for the cheapest retailer; and this might not be steam. After buying from Steam here in AU I noticed others sell for about half the price I paid :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All Civilization V version are basically the same because at the end all have to be registered on Steam, because it implements the Steam DRM.

Then could be that some reseller add some exclusive stuff:

#### Steam Standard edition

- Adds Cradle of Civilization Map Pack: Mesopotamia.

#### Steam Deluxe edition

- Adds Cradle of Civilization Map Pack: Mesopotamia.
- Plus also get the bonus Babylon Civilization with leader "Nebuchadnezzar II"
- Behind the Scenes at Firaxis with Civ V video feature
- Game Soundtrack

#### Play.com Edition

- Adds Cradle of Civilization Map Pack: Mesopotamia.

#### Collector's Edition

A boxed collector's edition is also coming. It should contains some miniatures, a book and possible other contents like soundtrack/make of.

The price should be around 100$.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The box version loads itself into Steam, so after you install, there is no difference between the two on your computer.

The boxed version includes a tech tree poster.  There is an important typo on it though.  It lists Archery as a dead end technology, which it isn't.  The "manual" is a two page flier on how to install the game.

Comment: "The "manual" is a two page flier on how to install the game." - That is disappointing. My copy of Civ IV had the most impressive manual I've seen in years.

Comment: For me, all of Civ 5 was a disappointment compared to 4. I do love 5, but it's the first Civ game that didn't cause me to uninstall its predecessor without looking back.

Comment: I wish the manual was the only thing that disappointed me of Civ5

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you source the game, it makes little difference. The game uses Steamworks, so it will be linked into Steam anyway.

With pre-orders from on-line retailers, you get the game at the same time (though you have to spend 15mins installing it), but you get it cheaper. In the UK, you are looking at £25 vs Steam's £30.